# iPOJO and service damping

Tags: osgi, ipojo, blueprint-osgi

[The comparison table for iPOJO](http://felix.apache.org/site/ipojo-faq.html#iPOJOFAQ-HowdoesiPOJOcomparetoDeclarativeServicesorBlueprint%253F) says it supports service damping, like Blueprint does. Does this just refer to [temporal dependencies](http://felix.apache.org/site/temporal-service-dependency.html) or other service dependencies as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, only temporal dependencies are supporting damping. However temporal dependencies are just regular (optional) dependencies, so it does not change much.

In addition, it's planned to integrate the 'temporal' aspect directly in the core.